# displaying numbers in a plot legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I was wondering why numerical values of `pop_mean = 10 ; pop_mean_sd = 5 ; within_sd = 3` don't show in the `legend` of my plot below? Is there a fix?

```
pop_mean = 10 ; pop_mean_sd = 5 ; within_sd = 3

plot(1)
legend("top",      c(expression(mu[i]*"~"*N(.(pop_mean)*","*.(pop_mean_sd))), 
                     expression(Math[ij]*"~"*N(mu[i]*","*.(within_sd)))),
                      bty = "n", cex = .8, 
                    inset = c(0, -.17), xpd = NA)
```

Comment: can you join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217273/room-for-akrun-and-rnorouzian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `bquote`.

From `help(bquote)`:

> An analogue of the LISP backquote macro. bquote quotes its argument
> except that terms wrapped in .() are evaluated in the specified where
> environment.

Therefore, anything within `.()` is evaluated, which should be what you're looking for. Using `c()` with `bquote` makes a list of calls, which doesn't work with `legend`. So you can use `as.expression` to convert to a usable expression.

```
plot(1)
legend("top",
       as.expression(c(bquote(mu[i]*"~"*N(.(pop_mean)*","*.(pop_mean_sd))),
                       bquote(Math[ij]*"~"*N(mu[i]*","*.(within_sd))))),
       bty = "n", cex = .8, 
       inset = c(0, 0), xpd = NA)
```

[image]

A similar approach could be with `substitute`:

```
legend("top",
       legend = as.expression(c(substitute(mu[i]*"~"*N(pop_mean*","*pop_mean_sd),
                                                 list(pop_mean=pop_mean, pop_mean_sd = pop_mean_sd)),
                                      substitute(italic(Math)[ij]*"~"*N(mu[i]*","*within_sd),
                                                 list(within_sd=within_sd)))),
       bty = "n", cex = .8, 
       inset = c(0, 0), xpd = NA)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `...bquote(italic(Math)...` seems to work OK.